# Handling missing values in function `prewhiten` in R

Tags: r, time-series

I am using function `prewhiten` from "TSA" package in R. I get an error about `NA` values, but I don't understand it, because I don't have `NA` values in my data. Here is the error message:

```
whitedata <- prewhiten(xhr, ypred, mod1)

Error in na.omit.ts(as.ts(x)) : all times contain an NA
```

It works fine for some data files, but not for others. When I print `xhr` and `ypred` I don't see any `NA` values.

Both are time series:

```
xhr <- ts(data$hr_z,start=1,frequency=10) #convert to a time series
ypred <- ts(data$pred_z,start=1,frequency=10) #convert to a time series
```

Strangely, if I run it with a different model (one built on `ypred`), it runs just fine. The model I am using is:

```
ARIMA(2,1,2)                    

Coefficients:
         ar1      ar2      ma1     ma2
      1.4835  -0.7641  -0.9574  0.4021
s.e.  0.1136   0.0826   0.1365  0.0910

sigma^2 estimated as 0.02589:  log likelihood=79.98
AIC=-149.96   AICc=-149.65   BIC=-133.55
```

Comment: Please add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536) for people to work with.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to use R without a reproducible example.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, but my data is confidential so I can't give it I would be more than happy to otherwise.

Comment: Scale your data and it won't be confidential anymore :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The description of the function `prewhiten`

> The bivariate time series are prewhitened according to an AR model fitted to the x-component of the bivariate series. Alternatively, if an ARIMA model is provided, it will be used to prewhiten both series. The CCF of the prewhitened bivariate series is then computed and plotted.

gives an impression that first the originally supplied series `x` and `y` are prewhitened and then the CCF is computed and plotted. It could be that the function `na.omit.ts` that actually gives you the error message kicks in *after* prewhitening but *before* computing the CCF. Then you cannot see the problem just by looking at the original series `x` and `y`; you should instead look at the output of the model that is used for prewhitening (before computing the CCF) -- you might find `NA` values there.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. What do you mean exactly? I tried print(Arima(ypred, model=mod1)), but that just shows me the model. How do I see what the prewhitening uses as input? Many thanks for your help

Comment: Try printing the model residuals and the fitted values (I guess `prewhiten` uses the residuals). `resid(model)` and `fitted(model)` should work.

Comment: Thanks, these values look good. At least for mod1 and the original data. I'm not sure how to display this for the second times series.

Comment: Oh, I guess resid(Arima(ypred, model=mod1)). Looks normal as well, mmm...

Comment: They all start like this: Time Series:
Start = c(1, 1) 
End = c(20, 8) 
Frequency = 10   And then contain data such as: 
  [1] -1.5348511458 -1.5859549941 -1.8592942286 -1.6205654133 -1.6870598355
  [6]  0.0866671433 -2.5737072280 -0.6033057751 -0.5033981250 -0.7526528031

Comment: Well, then my guess was wrong. Or there is something else that you can't see. But I do not have another idea for what else could have gone wrong. By the way, please use backticks \` for code pieces, that makes it easier to read.

Comment: Thanks though, I managed to get the results anyway by doing some sort of manual prewhitening using the fitted command you sent me: `fitwhite <- fitted(Arima(xhr, model=mod1))
 fitwhite2 <- fitted(Arima(ypred, model=mod1))
 print(ccf(fitwhite, fitwhite2))'  (sorry the quotes don't seem to work)

Comment: Well, apparently I was not explicit enough: you put the text in between two quotes: \`text\` to get `text`. What you did is put a backtick in the beginning but a simple quote at the end; that does not work. Both have to be backticks.